# Visual Studio 2012 - Gridview not displaying on webform

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I would like to give the user the ability to select only the data that he wants to see on a gridview instead of every column of a table. For example, I have every column displaying in a checkboxlist. If the user only selects name and address and hits submit, then on postback the name and address should display in the gridview. I have everything working correctly except the gridview is not displaying any data.

Here is my .aspx code:

```
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdminReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="WorkOrder.AdminReport" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

     <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="msgBoxLight.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.msgBox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Width="1020px">
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/mast_left.png" />          
        </asp:Panel>       
        </div>

        <div class="Section"> <hr /><h2>
            Online Work Order Form - (Admin Report)</h2>
        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Select data you want to view and click the submit button:" CssClass="label"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />       
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cbSelectData" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False"   AppendDataBoundItems="True" BorderStyle="Ridge" CellPadding="15" CellSpacing="2" RepeatColumns="6" BackColor="#FFD7AE">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
            <br /><br />

                <asp:Button ID="btnGetResults" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnGetResults_Click"/>

              <br />
         <asp:Label ID="Message" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <br />  <br />       

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select to filter by position:"></asp:Label>
        <br /> <br />  <br />
                <asp:GridView ID="GridViewReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   DataKeyNames="Names" EnableModelValidation ="True" EmptyDataText="No records to display">
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#0099CC" ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" ForeColor="White" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BorderColor="#0099FF" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using aejw.Network;

namespace WorkOrder
{
    public partial class AdminReport : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!Page.IsPostBack) // this keeps from loading everytime the page does a partial laod
            {
                LoadDataSource1();
            }

           this.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;

        }

        protected void btnGetResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            LoadDataSource2();         

        }

        protected void LoadDataSource1()
        {
            int i = 0;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string query1 = "SELECT Name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID (@ObjectID)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, conn);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ObjectID", "dbo.WO_Submission_Details");
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                cbSelectData.Items.Insert(i, rdr.GetValue(0).ToString());
                i++;
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        protected void LoadDataSource2()
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WOConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            string query2 = "SELECT Name FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID (@ObjectID)";
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, conn);
            conn.Open();
            {
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("ObjectID", cbSelectData.SelectedItem.ToString());
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                da.Fill(ds);
                GridViewReport.DataSource = ds;
                //cbSelectData.DataTextField = "Name";
                //cbSelectData.DataValueField = "Name";
                //cbSelectData.DataBind();
                GridViewReport.DataBind();

                conn.Close();
            }


        }

    }
}
```

I have the gridview binding to the datasource. Am I missing a step? Thanks

Comment: I assume that you've used the debugger. What was the result? What is the content of `ds.Tables[0]` in the debugger? Do you get any rows? Btw, you're using the same meta query as for the `CheckBoxList`.

Comment: The query is similar but the ObjectID is set to the checkbox list selectedItem.

Answer (score 0):

You have `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`, that means you want to specify the columns by providing [template-fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288032.aspx) or [bound-fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But you're not adding any column to the `GridView` in the aspx.

So change it to:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewReport" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ...
```

Here's an example of declaratively added columns:

```
....
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" 
        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CustomerID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" 
        SortExpression="CompanyName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" 
        SortExpression="FirstName" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" 
        SortExpression="LastName" />
</Columns>
....
```

Comment: I changed the AutoGenerateColumns="True" but it still isn't returning data.

Comment: Are you getting any data at all to return to the grid?